# Set restart container in dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

How do I can restart docker container? I dont have access to Jenkins, only by docker file. I want to set restart container after spend 24 hours. Can I do it with some commands in dockerfile?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the restart policy cannot be set directly in the Dockerfile itself.
to do this create a shell

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTAINER_NAME="your-container-name"
docker container stop $CONTAINER_NAME
docker container start $CONTAINER_NAME
```

add permission to the file by

```
    chmod +x that_file.sh
```

then Use a scheduler tool (e.g., cron) on your host machine to execute the shell script after 24 hours.

open chrontab in editing mode and schedule restart on host machine.

```
   crontab -e
   0 0 * * * /path/to/that_file.sh
```